# Finding the unitary matrix that minimizes an objective function based on singular values

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors, nonlinear-optimization, information-theory

The problem I'm trying to solve is the following. Given an input tensor $A_{ij}^{\alpha\beta}$, I want to find the unitary tensor $U^{ij}_{kl}$ such that the function $f = -\sum_i s_i^2\log s_i^2$ is minimized, where the $s_i$ are the singular values of the vectorization $U^{ij}_{kl}A_{ij}^{\alpha\beta} = X^{\alpha\beta}_{kl}\rightarrow X_{(\alpha i)(\beta j)}$.

I've tried a few computational approaches involving parameterizing the matrix $U$ using a Cayley transform, then applying various optimization methods, but I haven't found something that consistently finds an optimal or near-optimal solution.

Is there a better way of solving this problem? Even if there is no direct analytic solution, is a more natural parameterization that would make the cost function surface smoother?

Comment: If $U$ is unitary, then the singular values of $UA$ are always equal to those of $A$. In other words, your objective function is constant which means that "minimizing it" is either trivial or meaningless, depending on your perspective.

Comment: You're right -- I wasn't thinking. I've updated the problem with what I meant.

Comment: What does it mean for a rank $(2,2)$ tensor to be "unitary"?

Comment: $U_{kl}^{ij}^* U_{mn}^{ij}$ and $U_{kl}^{ij}^* U_{mn}^{pr}$  are identity tensors, and if we vectorized again $U_{kl}^{ij}^* U_{mn}^{ij} = I^{kl}_{mn}\rightarrow I_{(kl)(mn)}$ would be an identity matrix.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! Don't think I'll be much help now that I understand the question, unfortunately.